# How to make a Symfony 2 bundle with an optional dependency?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

Say that your bundle use some RESTful service and can work with two different PHP HTTP clients: [guzzle/guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) as well as with [kriswallsmith/Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz). Because it uses adapters and interfaces.

How can I defined this dependency as optional? Would you do something like this, for example in compiler pass?

```php
if(!is_file('/path/to/guzzle') && !is_file('/path/to/buzz')) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('You need to install guzzle or Buzz browser.');
}
```

Is this the right way to define an optional dependency for a bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would not do it like the above, mainly because checking if files are present at some path won't work. What if the user installs them somewhere else (for whatever reason) and manages to get namespacing right?

My first question would be why you want the user to choose. Is there any difference? Is the user even capable of deciding which client to use. For example when I use assetics, I of course have to decide which filters I want to use, because they have a big impact on what happens (e.g. if I have scss files, a less filter is useless).

There are other problems like the one that the user has to manage dependencies himself. Sometimes this is worth it, sometimes it's not.

Now, if you decided you want the user to choose, I would go for a configuration option where the user passes either the string guzzle or the string buzz. Maybe there is a default value.

In your bundle, you try to create your object depending on this configuration. You could surround it with a try catch block to catch missing dependencies or see if a certain class is avaiable. As said, you would not test for the existence of a certain file, but of a certain class with the php function `class_exists`. Your test should be on the class or classes you actually want to use.

Comment: I'd like to underline the questioning of usefulness for this choice. Your module probably cannot work without HTTP client, so neither of both dependencies are really optional. You'll need at least one dependency resolved.

Comment: Thanks. As @Sven has suggested, the bundle needs at least one dependency. If you think better at this, why would you force the user to install - say guzzle - if he has already buzz and the bundle can work with the latter? Anyways I'll go for the configuration way, passing the service (the browser) and checking it with instanceof operator.

Comment: Your library obviously does not support MY HTTP client of choice, so I have to install any one of your dependencies. Which one should it be, and why? I won't extend your library to use mine, and I won't go into research mode to get an idea of which of your suggested clients is better. I probably even won't be bothered with the details of why your library prefers one client over the other. But still I have a choice to make, and it does not work out-of-the-box. Bottom line: I question the usefulness of users choice at this point, but discussing it means discussing your librarys design decisions.

Comment: @Sven interesting point. You think that letting the user choose the http client is useless?

Comment: I think that the user cannot decide which of the possible alternatives is "better". Either he is surprised by the possibility to use the one he already uses, but still the question remains whether the other alternatives would be better. You as the library vendor should know which client is better. Unless PHP libraries agree on a common interface for common tasks, and therefore make the Composer option of defining a dependency on a virtual "http client" package actually useful, there is no way for the user to make an educated choice - so YES, this feature is actually useless.